# How can I Monetize a Google Data Studio Connector?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to understand how to monetize GDS connectors once are publicated in the community. Does something know how to do it. I can't find a clue on this on the URL: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started

Answer (score 2):

Monetization is entirely upto the developer. You will need to implement your own payment and verification for this.

You can verify the user identify and level of access through either your own 3P authentication for the connector OR by calling your own API with the effective user's email address.